# What is Wrong with my code to find prime numbers?

Tags: java, loops

For this assignment I need to take in a serious of inputs until 0 is entered which will terminate the code. After the input of each number it needs to output whether that number was prime or not. Then after inputting zero the code should stop and give some description of the numbers entered such as max, min, sum, etc.

My issue is that regardless of what number I put in, it says that every number is prime and I cannot seem to understand why. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment4 
{
public static void main (String[] args) 
{
    int input;
    int max = 0;
    int min = 100000000;
    double sum = 0;
    int count= 0;
    double average = 0;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean isPrime;

    do 
    {
        System.out.println("Enter a postive integer. Enter 0 to quit");
        input = scan.nextInt();
        for (int i =2; i<= input/2; i++) //Determine if prime
        {
            if (input % i == 0)
                isPrime = false;
            else
                isPrime = true;

            if (isPrime = true)
                System.out.println("The number " + input + " is a prime number");
            else
                System.out.println("The number " + input + " is not a prime number");

            if (input > max)
            {
                max = input;
            }
            if (input < min)
            {
                min = input;
            }
            sum += input;
            count = count + 1;
            average = sum/count;
            break;
        }

    }
    while (input != 0);
    System.out.println("The Max is " + max);
    System.out.println("The Min is " + min);
    System.out.println("The sum is " + sum);
    System.out.println("The total numbers are " + count);
    System.out.println("The average is " + average);


}   

}
```

Comment: One thing: an assignment is being done in the if statement: `if (isPrime = true)`. Change that to `if (isPrime == true)` or even better: `if (isPrime)`

Comment: If you step through your code in your debugger you would be able to see that you don't check all the values of `i` before printing your output. You also don't check `if (isPrime == true)` or `if(isPrime)` you assign it to true so it is always true.

Comment: Instead of using `int min = 100000000;` it would be better to use `Integer.MAX_INT`

Comment: How to I declare Integer.MAX_INT? Do I need to import a class?

Comment: Oh sorry... It's called `Integer.MAX_VALUE` :D Just write `int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David Sherret is correct, you have an error in that if statement. It needs to change to `if( isPrime )`.

Also, you are printing the results of every `input % i` test. That output should happen after the for loop.

Right now, when testing 15, your code will print out:
The number 15 is a prime number
The number 15 is not a prime number
The number 15 is a prime number
The number 15 is not a prime number
The number 15 is a prime number
The number 15 is a prime number

This is because:

```
(15 % 2) equals 1
(15 % 3) equals 0
(15 % 4) equals 3
(15 % 5) equals 0
(15 % 6) equals 3
(15 % 7) equals 1
```

and you are printing the results for each of these tests.

Before the `for` loop, initialize `isPrime` with `true` and then only set it to `false` inside the loop if the number is not prime. Then, test `isPrime` *after* the loop and print the statement. Like this:

```
isPrime = true;
for (int i =2; i<= input/2; i++) //Determine if prime
{
    if (input % i == 0)
        isPrime = false;

    if (input > max)
    {
        max = input;
    }
    if (input < min)
    {
        min = input;
    }
    sum += input;
    count = count + 1;
    average = sum/count;
    break;
}

if (isPrime)
    System.out.println("The number " + input + " is a prime number");
else
    System.out.println("The number " + input + " is not a prime number");
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 3):

You are setting `isPrime` to true if `i` is not a divisor. If the last `i` you check is **not** a divisor, `isPrime` will be false even though there might have been a divisor in a previous iteration.

Solution: Remove the assignment to false and set `isPrime` to true before starting the `for` loop:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment4  {
    public static void main (String[] args)  {
        int input;
        int max = 0;
        int min = 100000000;
        double sum = 0;
        int count= 0;
        double average = 0;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean isPrime;

        do 
        {
            System.out.println("Enter a postive integer. Enter 0 to quit");
            input = scan.nextInt();
            isPrime = true; // I added this line
            for (int i =2; i<= input/2; i++) //Determine if prime
            {
                if (input % i == 0) {
                    isPrime = false;
                    break;
                } 
                //else
                //    isPrime = true;
            } 
            if (isPrime)
                System.out.println("The number " + input + " is a prime number");
            else
                System.out.println("The number " + input + " is not a prime number");

            if (input > max)
            {
                max = input;
            }
            if (input < min)
            {
                min = input;
            }
            sum += input;
            count = count + 1;
            average = sum/count;

        }
        while (input != 0);
        System.out.println("The Max is " + max);
        System.out.println("The Min is " + min);
        System.out.println("The sum is " + sum);
        System.out.println("The total numbers are " + count);
        System.out.println("The average is " + average);


    }   
}
```

*Code untested, I am on my phone currently*

**Fun fact:**
You just need to loop to `Math.sqrt(input)` (square root). To illustrate it: If `input/2` is a divisor, `2` is a divisor too ;)

Comment: Thank you for the help. Makes sense now :)

Answer (score 2):

I can see a few problems:

1) Change:

```
if (input % i == 0)
            isPrime = false;
        else
            isPrime = true;
```

To:

```
if (input % i == 0)
    isPrime = false;
```

And insert

```
isPrime=true;
```

before the for loop.

(Because just because the current value of i is not a divisor does not make it prime).

2) Change:

```
if (isPrime = true)
```

To:

```
if (isPrime==true)
```

Or:

```
if (isPrime)
```

3) Delete break;

4) Check if isPrime is true outside the loop, after *all* the divisors have been checked, not in it.

5) Check values of i up to and including the square root of input, not half of it. It's quicker.

Comment: If you clarify that `isPrime = true;` needs to be called **before** starting the `for` loop, I will upvote your answer ;) Currently it's basically the same than if/else

Comment: Just edit your answer to include a short explanation to the second code snippet

Comment: @ByteHamster Yeah, I will. I was in a rush when I wrote this, so I didn't have time.